# Creating a non-bias dataframe from a bias dataset in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working with the [COMPAS dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/danofer/compass) and looking to create two Pandas DataFrame with the data --one with bias and one without, by splitting the set into two. As of now, I have the below working that will create one dataframe, but it will carry over the bias originally found in COMPAS because "replace" must be set to True given the distribution in size between races.

```
import os
import tempfile
import urllib

_DATA_ROOT = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix='tfx-data')
_DATA_PATH = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/what-if-tool-resources/computefest2019/cox-violent-parsed_filt.csv'
_DATA_FILEPATH = os.path.join(_DATA_ROOT, 'compas-scores-two-years.csv')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(_DATA_PATH, _DATA_FILEPATH)

_COMPAS_DF = _COMPAS_DF[_COMPAS_DF['is_recid'] != -1]
_GROUPBY_DF = _COMPAS_DF.groupby('race')
_COMPAS_DF = _GROUPBY_DF.apply(lambda x: x.sample(5000, replace=True).reset_index(drop=True))
_COMPAS_DF['race'].value_counts()
```

The output of this dataframe is below but the bias of 'is_recid', which is a bool value of the defendant's recidivism stays the same.

```
African-American    5000
Other               5000
Caucasian           5000
Asian               5000
Hispanic            5000
Native American     5000
Name: race, dtype: int64
```

The starting dataframe is listed below:

```
is_recid  Race              Count is_recid  
0         African-American  4338    24.79%
          Caucasian         3308    18.91%
          Hispanic          860     4.92%
          Other             502     2.87%
          Asian             45      0.26%
          Native American   26      0.15%
1         African-American  5081    29.04%
          Caucasian         2474    14.14%
          Hispanic          495     2.83%
          Other             323     1.85%
          Native American   25      0.14%
          Asian             19      0.11%
Total                       17496   100.00%
```

My hope is to create a dataframe like the below and a second dataframe with the remaining values from the original dataset. Note that the count doesn't necessarily need to be exactly as listed but the distribution between race and is_recid is balanced.

```
is_recid  Race              Count   is_recid    
0         African-American  3000    29.85%
          Caucasian         1500    14.93%
          Hispanic          300     2.99%
          Other             200     1.99%
          Asian             10      0.10%
          Native American   15      0.15%
1         African-American  3000    29.85%
          Caucasian         1500    14.93%
          Hispanic          300     2.99%
          Other             200     1.99%
          Native American   15      0.15%
          Asian             10      0.10%
Total                       10050   100.00%
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The below ended up working for me:

```
_COMPAS_DF_TUPLES = dict(tuple(_COMPAS_DF.groupby(['race', 'is_recid'])))
_UNBIASED_COMPAS = pd.DataFrame()
_BIASED_COMPAS = pd.DataFrame()

for race in _COMPAS_DF['race'].unique():
  # Find the minimum difference between race and is_recid to create an unbiased
  # dataset.
  min_bias_count = min(_COMPAS_DF_TUPLES[(race, 0)].shape[0],
                       _COMPAS_DF_TUPLES[(race, 1)].shape[0])

  # Split the data into two DataFrames --one biased and one unbiased.
  _UNBIASED_COMPAS = pd.concat(
      [_COMPAS_DF_TUPLES[(race, 0)][:min_bias_count], _UNBIASED_COMPAS])
  _UNBIASED_COMPAS = pd.concat(
      [_COMPAS_DF_TUPLES[(race, 1)][:min_bias_count], _UNBIASED_COMPAS])

  _BIASED_COMPAS = pd.concat(
      [_COMPAS_DF_TUPLES[(race, 0)][min_bias_count:], _BIASED_COMPAS])
  _BIASED_COMPAS = pd.concat(
      [_COMPAS_DF_TUPLES[(race, 1)][min_bias_count:], _BIASED_COMPAS])
```